# Trending Slowly Changing Data

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, data-warehouse, bids

So, i'm having trouble coming up with a solution to my issue.

We have just implemented a number of fact/dimensions to bring slowly changing data into our warehouse. The scenario is that we monitor tickets and we implemented SCD so we could run reports that show open tickets historically (this day last week or on the 1st of the month) rather than the DBs current state. I would like to show how many tickets were open in a trend graph over a number of days.

```
Example Data 
ID; Open Count; Effective From; Effective To; 
1; 1; 28/02/2016; 05/03/2016 
2; 1; 02/03/2016; 04/03/2016 
3; 1; 03/03/2016; 04/03/2016
```

[Charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrl1Z.png)

I would like to produce the chart on the right, but i end up with the chart on the left. I whiped up a brief code snippet that were using.

```
> SELECT DT.Date, SUM(Open_Count) FROM ExampleDate ED   LEFT JOIN
> DateTime Dimension DT ON ED.Effective_From = DT.Date WHERE
>   ED.Effective_From >= '28/02/2016' AND ED.Effective_From <
> '06/03/2016' ORDER BY DT.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Im going to assume your fact table layout means that ID:1 was considered open between 28/2 and 5/3

Problem is your join - The result you are after requires the ticket records to be duplicated for each day they are open... try:

```
select
  DT.Date, 
  SUM(Open_Count) 
FROM 
  DateTime_Dimension DT 
  inner JOIN ExampleDate ED ON DT.Date  >= ED.Effective_From and DT.Date  <= ED.Effective_To
WHERE
  ED.Effective_From >= '28/02/2016' AND ED.Effective_From < '06/03/2016' 
GROUP BY 
  DT.Date
ORDER BY 
  DT.Date
```